# Cambiar color click por click

Tags: javascript

Quiero que cada vez que de click al boton vaya cambiando el color del resto de los span, ya que con este ejemplo solo elije a uno (el primero) y no a los demás ¿que falta?

```js
function color() {
var color = document.querySelector(".content > span");

color.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
</div>

<br/>

<button onclick="color()">Agregar color</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrias que obtener todos los spans con querySelectorAll y posteriormente recorrer el arreglo con forEach y asi poder cambiar el color a cada span.

```js
var colores = document.querySelectorAll(".content > span");
var count = 0;
function color() {
  if(count < colores.length) {
     colores[count].style.color = "red";
  }
  count++;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
<br/>

<button onclick="color()">Agregar color</button>
```